# Permutations using python

Tags: python

Im trying to find all possible permutations but get duplicates when I use itertools.permuatations method.

```
import itertools
def solution(A):
    for each in itertools.permutations(list(A)):
        print each
        print '----'

solution('1214')
```

result:--

```
('1', '2', '1', '4')
----
('1', '2', '4', '1')
----
('1', '1', '2', '4')
----
('1', '1', '4', '2')
----
('1', '4', '2', '1')
----
('1', '4', '1', '2')
----
('2', '1', '1', '4')
----
('2', '1', '4', '1')
----
('2', '1', '1', '4')
----
('2', '1', '4', '1')
----
('2', '4', '1', '1')
----
('2', '4', '1', '1')
----
('1', '1', '2', '4')
----
('1', '1', '4', '2')
----
('1', '2', '1', '4')
----
('1', '2', '4', '1')
----
('1', '4', '1', '2')
----
('1', '4', '2', '1')
----
('4', '1', '2', '1')
----
('4', '1', '1', '2')
----
('4', '2', '1', '1')
----
('4', '2', '1', '1')
----
('4', '1', '1', '2')
----
('4', '1', '2', '1')
----
```

Comment: But your input is `('1214')`. Should that be `('1234')`? Otherwise, what would your expected output look like? Still 4 digits, but no duplicates?

Comment: Since there are two 1's you should expect duplicates.

Comment: This is a messy problem, and thankfully a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You get duplicates because the input has two `1` characters in it.  You can use `set()` to remove them.

```
import itertools
def solution(A):
    for each in set(itertools.permutations(list(A))):
        print each
        print '----'

solution('1214')
```